# iOS App will not follow the device region settings

Tags: ios, localization

In my iOS project (in the info.plist) I have:

```
Localization native development region = Germany
```

My device is also set to German/Germany.

Still, standard UIBarButtonItems are showing the titles "Cancel" and "Save" in english language. Am I missing something?!

Comment: You need to introduce Internalization in your app for this purpose, dont you?
I think you need to create separate nibs or localized text strings and then in your code you need to refer that nib or that localized string to  change Bar button titles and other stuff.

Comment: Not for standard UIControls actually.

Comment: Puneet is right, unless you add localization, standard controls won't be localized.

Comment: You are right I had to add localization in the project settings.